# Get global settings with Vue 3, Laravel, Vuex, axios

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios, vuex

I am using Laravel 8, Vue 3 with vuex, axios.
I created an API at `domain.com/api/settings` to store global settings as: app name, store name, store description, ... These parameters are used in many components: MainHeader, MainFooter, child component

API domain.com/api/settings

```
{"data":[{"name":"app_name","val":"Laravel App"},{"name":"store_name","val":"Golf"},{"name":"store_description","val":"This is meta description"}]}
```

app.js

```
import { createApp, onMounted } from 'vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import MainHeader from './components/layouts/MainHeader.vue'
import MainFooter from './components/layouts/MainFooter.vue'

const app = createApp({})
app.component('main-header', MainHeader)
   .component('main-footer', MainFooter)
app.use(router).use(store).mount('#app')
```

I can use API in seperated component like this:

resources/js/composables/settings.js

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'

export default function useSettings() {
    const settings = ref({})    
    const getSettings = async () => {
        let response = await axios.get('/api/settings/')
        settings.value = response.data.data.reduce((obj, item) => (obj[item.name] = item.val, obj) ,{})
    }    
    return {
        settings,
        getSettings,
    }
}
```

resources/js/components/layouts/MainFooter.vue

```
<template>
     {{ settings.store_name }}
</template>
<script setup>
import { onMounted } from 'vue'
import useSettings from '../../composables/settings.js'

const { settings, getSettings } = useSettings()
onMounted(getSettings)
</script>
```

I wrote same code for MainHeader.vue, Contact.vue so the contact page will call API 3 times.

I tried to create `js/store/index.js` but it is not working

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'

export default createStore({
  state: {
     settings: () => {
         const settings = ref({})

         let response = axios.get('/api/settings/')
         settings.value = response.data.data.reduce((obj, item) => (obj[item.name] = item.val, obj) ,{})

        return {
             settings
         }
      }
   }
})
```

Comment: The store will obviously not work this way because you can't use asynchronous code as synchronous. Comps that rely on fetched settings shouldn't be rendered until data is ready to use. In Vue 3 you can use suspense in top-level comp to not render nested comps

Comment: Can you explain more or give me some keywords to search?

Comment: `but it is not working` - in what way? do you have errors occurring? "it is not working" is a nothing statement to make - if it were working, you wouldn't be asking :p

Comment: As said, it's suspense, https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html#async-setup

Comment: @JaromandaX variable `settings` gets nothing. No errors was found